# Keeping flexbox container and overflowing children within 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with 3 sections. The idea is that each section will be like an accordion and expand, but with any one of them expanded, I need the sections content to overflow vertically only if it would push the whole container past 100% height of the parent, while keeping within 100% of the height of the flexbox's container's container.

Here's a snippet of what I've tried with percentage heights.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#a {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#b {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}

#c {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#s2 {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"><div>Section 1</div></div>
    <div id="b">
      <div>Section 2</div>
      <div id="s2">
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c"><div>Section 3</div></div>
</div>
```

What I'd like is to be able to get something like the following snippet, but without specifying explicit heights of the parent element or flex items.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#a {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#b {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}

#c {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#s2 {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"><div>Section 1</div></div>
    <div id="b">
      <div>Section 2</div>
      <div id="s2">
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c"><div>Section 3</div></div>
</div>
```

Note that Section 3 takes up the slack remaining from Section 2's inferred flex-basis. I want Section 2 to grow to 100% and then overflow. Is this even possible with flexbox?

I was overwhelmed with similar-sounded questions, the closest of which I believe are:

[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space) - This is very similar but my question adds the "needs to scroll if it overflows 100%".

[Child with max-height: 100% overflows parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262938/child-with-max-height-100-overflows-parent) - I think this is the root of the problem. Without having a set parent height, it cannot calculate the height to overflow from.

[How to make a flexbox container to scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358177/how-to-make-a-flexbox-container-to-scroll) - Again a flex-basis of pixel units is needed. :(.

I'm able to using `display: tables` or other solutions. After typing this out I'm thinking that a javascript solution will be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJYwmq

The problem is that items inside flexboxes have an implicit "min-height" equals to it's real height. You can set it's `min-height: 0px`.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#b {
  flex: 100% 1 1;
  min-height: 0px; // this is important!
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex; // make it a flex too so you have better control of the scrollbar
  flex-direction: column;
}

#s2 {
  min-height: 0px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost good. Simply make the `#b` element to be a flexbox container too and with [`overflow:hidden` or `min-height:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#a {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#b {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  /*added this*/
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  /**/
}

#c {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#s2 {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"><div>Section 1</div></div>
    <div id="b">
      <div>Section 2</div>
      <div id="s2">
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c"><div>Section 3</div></div>
</div>
```

Instead of making the `#b` a flexbox container you can also consider `height:100%` on `s2`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#a {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#b {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#c {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#s2 {
  height:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"><div>Section 1</div></div>
    <div id="b">
      <div>Section 2</div>
      <div id="s2">
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c"><div>Section 3</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#b` section of your accordion *fills the remaining space* in the `#container` - so what you can do is split this vertical space among its contents - the *heading* and the `#s2`:

- make `#b` a *flexbox* with `flex-direction: column`
- also remember to set `min-height: 0` for `#b` (`min-height` is *auto* by default for a *flex item*)
- `flex: 1` would be enough in `#b` instead of `flex: 2 1 auto`
- also add `flex: 1` to `#s2` so that it *fills the remaining space* inside `#b` (you can drop the `max-height: 100%`).

See demo below:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#a {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#b {
  flex: 1; /* this would do */
  display: flex; /* added*/
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}

#c {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#s2 {
  flex: 1; /* added */
  /* max-height: 100%;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"><div>Section 1</div></div>
    <div id="b">
      <div>Section 2</div>
      <div id="s2">
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c"><div>Section 3</div></div>
</div>
```

---

Now you have *full-viewport accordion* - you can also let the `#container` to take only as much space as it needs when an accordion item is expanded and allow it to expand till the viewport height and overflow only afterwards - just change `height: 100%` in `container` to `max-height: 100%` - see demo below:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; /* changed to max-height */
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#a {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#b {
  flex: 1; /* this would do */
  display: flex; /* added*/
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}

#c {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#s2 {
  flex: 1; /* added */
  /* max-height: 100%;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a"><div>Section 1</div></div>
    <div id="b">
      <div>Section 2</div>
      <div id="s2">
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
       <div>Item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c"><div>Section 3</div></div>
</div>
```